# Groovy class not available in gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

I have a `kotlin/spring` project so I have this folder structure:

```
- src
  - main
    - groovy  
      - org.gradle.tasks
          CoreTask.groovy 
    - kotlin  
      - org.backend.srs
          MainApplication.kt  
          - services  
          - repositories  
          - dao
```

In my `build.gradle` I have:

```
...    
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
...
task core << {
  CoreTask coreTask = new CoreTask()
}
```

However IntelliJ IDEA Is complaining class does not exist. Even if I try to import it `import org.gradle.tasks.CoreTask` is not found.

Comment: Are you really sure that your question is Kotlin related? It looks like a Gradle only problem.

Comment: @RafalG. Removed the kotling tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your class to be available to the build, it needs to be in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy` (as in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources))